# php laravel Eloquent ORM relations

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I am codding on php and for current project I am using laravel framework (with Eloquent ORM). In this project I created two tables: users and tasks. I want create a relation "one to many" between this tables. So one user can have many tasks. In Tasks class I created method owner():

```
public function owner() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'tasks_owner_foreign');
}

(key <i>tasks_owner_foreign</i> (column: owner) references on <i>users</i> (id))
```

but when I used To get User name

```
$task->owner()->name
```

I get this exception:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: /path to file/tasks.blade.php)

if I used

```
$task->owner->name
```

I get this exception:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /path to file/tasks.blade.php)

What can it be? Or what make I wrong?

I think it will be useful https://github.com/sergeymarchuk/project

Comment: Try `$task->users['name']`

Comment: `Task->table_name['column_name']`

Comment: it is work but nothing displayed

Comment: it doesn't work because the relationship isn't set right

Comment: how is set relationship right?

Comment: According to your GITHUB, `$table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('users');` is your foreign key, it is most definitely not `tasks_owner_foreign` but it IS `owner`. You should try it before saying that's not the correct solution

Comment: I tried how you write above, but var_dump($task->users) displayed NULL. What is mean?

Comment: Your relationship between those tables aren't set up properly

Comment: Try `$task->owner['name']`

Answer (score 1):

There is no column called `tasks_owner_foreign` on ur tasktable migration.
[Ur task table migrations](https://github.com/sergeymarchuk/project/blob/master/database/migrations/2018_01_13_174622_create_tasks_table.php)

u used `owner` instead

```
public function getowner() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'owner');
}
```

Comment: this not worked, "tasks_owner_foreign" it is foreign key, which automatic created when you run migrate "create_tasks_table".